# ssh client failed to connect to AWS ec2 instance of nix platform in which public IP disabled

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services

I created ec2 instance of ubuntu platform in *AWS*. I set its **network/security** configurations as followings:

- disabled public IP address
- chose default VPC given
- for inbound rules:

  - port range: 22
  - protocol: TCP
  - source: 0.0.0.0/0
- outbound rules:

  - port range: all
  - port protocol: all
  - destination: 0.0.0.0/0

I tried to access the server via ssh client (e.g. PuTTY) using ppk file (ssh public key authentication) hitting private IP address but it failed to connect.

However if I enable public IP address, I can connect to it just fine.

My question is, with private IP address available only, can I access the server remotely via ssh client tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you will need public ip to ssh in

the private addresses are used if you have multiple EC2 instances to network

If you are worried about security, what can do is limit the inbound of the public only to port 22 and your ip range (note: if from home, it's your routers external ip)